# No /dev/mmcblk0 during boot

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, kernel

I am trying to install CentOS-6 on an eMMC drive. Since the supported 2.6.xx kernel from CentOS-6 doesn't support mmc, I compiled a newer kernel (4.2.6) which has updated mmc drivers. I tried booting using this kernel, but I still don't see `/dev/mmcblk0`.

When the boot exits to a shell without finding `/dev/mmcblk0`, I see that `mmc_core`, `mmc_block` and `sdhci_acpi` modules are loaded. Does anyone know how to make this available during boot ?

The same procedure works fine with the FC22/23 which has a 4.2.x kernel. What am I missing here ? Thanks for any hint.

*** EDIT

Here is the dmesg output.
http://pastebin.com/STq4LuwK

*** Correction

`mmc_block` module is NOT loaded. Only `mmc_core` and `sdhci-acpi` and `sdhci`

*** EDIT-1

Changing udev rules inside initrd image, I could load `mmc_block`, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: First of all: please attach a dmesg output

Comment: definitely, by Tuesday... no access to machine... happy holidays...

Comment: @silvio dmesg output is added along with a correction...

Comment: So, a kernel from Centos works, but your custom kernel did not ? Then you did not build the modules needed for your hard drive. See also https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7osSv1YTKAhVK3mMKHUCiCjoQFggnMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebv.com%2Ffileadmin%2Fdesign_solutions%2Fphp%2Fdownload.php%3Fpath%3Dfileadmin%252Fproducts%252FEBVuniversity%252F120912_Micron_e.MMC%252F120912_mic_emmc_Linux.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE64f-mETHSlPZVfZtMGPCiUzUV-w&sig2=aNu1ilVCwc4hI3JuKLJJ1g&bvm=bv.110151844,d.cGc

Comment: @bodhi.zazen CentOS kernel-2.6.xxx does not work. Only FC22 onwards work. I am compiling latest mmc drivers with the same `CONFIG_MMC_*` as the FC22/23. That doesn't help. I must be missing some other module that is not obvious...

Comment: Investigate from a working kernel. I gave you several links thta shoul dhelp. depmod ...

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, for my particular system, a kernel config was missing. It was the LPSS support from Intel. `CONFIG_X86_INTEL_LPSS` which has the particular support for `80860F14` acpi peripheral and needed for my Samsung eMMC drive. After including this, mmc block and core drivers could see `/dev/mmcblk0`.

Comment: FYI postmarketOS has list of checks of config options in their CI: https://gitlab.com/postmarketOS/pmbootstrap/-/blob/master/pmb/config/__init__.py#L287

Answer (score 1):

1. Different kernels might not use the same names for block devices. It is preferred that you add a label to your block device and look for it `/dev/disk/by-label`.
2. If you suspect that some module, enabled in Fedora kernels, is missing from your kernel configuration, you can get Fedora's kernel configuration and start from there:

   zcat /proc/config.gz > config