# Identifying disk drives during RHEL/CentOS/Fedora Installation

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, rhel, kernel

What steps are followed in order to identify a connected disk drive during Linux installation ? I am interested RHEL/CentOS/Fedora procedures. Is it entirely depends on the Kernel package and drivers ? Is there more to just getting the right/updated drivers in order to identify/recognize a connected hardware(disk) during installation ?

I am trying to understand this process as part of my [other U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251376/no-dev-mmcblk0-during-boot), which no one seemed interested.

Comment: The hardware driver(s) are a part of the kernel and can either built into the kernel or built as a module which the kernel loads on as as needed basis. If you are asking how krenel modules work, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules and the kernel documentation. Otherwise your question is too broad.